# Failed to bind properties under 'logging.level.com.netflix.eureka' to org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, netflix-eureka

i'm using Eureka Server with Spring Boot.
The Error:

```
org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'logging.level.com.netflix.eureka' to org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel
```

pom.xml

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=eureka-server
server.port=8761

# avoid registering itself as a client
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=ON
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=ON
```

Comment: Hi, fellow Udacian :)

Answer (score 8):

You are using an invalid value for your two properties:

```
logging.level.com.netflix.eureka
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery
```

How you can see in your stash, you have to set one of the supported values from enum class: org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel

```
package org.springframework.boot.logging;

public enum LogLevel {

    TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, OFF

}
```

So for example if you want to see debug level messages and above you can set it like that:

```
logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=debug
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=debug
```